# Windows Disk Management tells me "Disk is not initialized." What does that mean?

Tags: windows, backup, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a disk I need to recover, but the problem is that when I connect it via USB to my Windows, machine, Disk Management tells me `Disk is not initialized`. When I try to initialize the disk, either in `MBR` or `GPT` format, I get an `Unknown Function` error.

First, how can I reinitialize the disk, and second, how do I recover the data I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "Initializing" your disk is going to format it.  So you probably don't want to do that.

What you want to do is restore from the backups you took.

But since you don't have backups, your options are trying to get a block-level copy of the disk, if you can, and then pulling your hair out to recover data from that, or sending it off to a data recovery expert.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have backups then http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm maybe a good solution for you.